# Is there a shorter way to do this in Javascript? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, project, calculator

I'm making a calculator, and I'm adding `eventListeners` to the number buttons.
JS looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if (e.target.matches('#num1')){
        const x = document.createElement('p');
        x.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        screen.appendChild(x)
    }
    else if (e.target.matches('#num2')){
        const x = document.createElement('p');
        x.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        screen.appendChild(x)
    } 

    else if (e.target.matches('#num3')){
        const x = document.createElement('p');
        x.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        screen.appendChild(x)
    } 
})
```

It's working alright, but there are 10 number buttons obviously, so I tried to make it shorter with tenary operators, or make a function out of this part:

```
        const x = document.createElement('p');
        x.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        screen.appendChild(x)
```

However, this way e.target is undefined.  Any suggestions appreciated!

Markup:

```
<button type='button' class='btn numBtn' id='num1'>1</button>
<button type='button' class='btn numBtn' id='num2'>2</button>
<button type='button' class='btn numBtn' id='num3'>3</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the class instead of the ID.

Since you aren't deliberately inserting or retrieving HTML markup, you should also use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, it's safer, quicker, and more semantically appropriate.

```
document.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if (e.target.matches('.numBtn')){
        const x = document.createElement('p');
        x.textContent = e.target.textContent;
        screen.appendChild(x)
    }
})
```

You can also use `insertAdjacentHTML`, though this has the same problems as `innerHTML`.

```
document.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if (e.target.matches('.numBtn')){
        screen.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<p>${e.target.textContent}</p>`
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I didn't think of that solution...